# Proof that $e^x>0$ from exponential law

Tags: real-analysis

I am going through a book on Real Analysis and have to prove that $$e^x>0$$ from the exponential laws: $$e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$$ and $$e^0=1$$

I thought of using the second law listed here by noticing that $x=x+0$:
$e^x=e^{x+0}=e^xe^0=e^x$
But this doesn't help me any further.

Comment: $e^{x}=(e^{x/2})^{2} \geq 0$ and  $e^{x}e^{-x}=e^{0}=1$ so $e^{x} \neq 0$.

Comment: @geetha290krm that looks good.

Comment: $x$ is an invariant here....so just check for $1,0,-1$

Comment: @geetha290krm Why not an official answer?

Comment: Just in case, it should be emphasized that saying $e^x=(e^{x/2})^2$ is potentially dangerous.  It works here because $e$ is positive, however in general $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ can be false in the event that $a$ is not a positive real number.  Be sure to keep an eye out for this and other nuances when moving towards complex analysis.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the warning! I'll bear this in mind when I study Complex Analysis.

Comment: @JMoravitz Is my approach correct? Without exponental rule? I would write ,let $x\in\mathbb R$, and $e^x=a\implies x=\ln a \implies a>0$ and $\ln a$ is defined for only $a>0$. If $a≤0$, then $\ln a$ is not defined in reals.

Comment: @User that sounds very circular.  With problems like this it must be very carefully stated what knowledge is given and what definitions are being used.  Anything which is not stated as part of the definition must be proven separately and it is probable that the source of this exercise chose to define the exponential function first and define the logarithm after, the properties of the logarithm coming from the properties of the exponential.  You may have inadvertently used this result to prove itself which is not allowed.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for your explanation. I understood

Comment: @JMoravitz  If I use $$e^{x}≥x+1$$ So if $x≥0$, then $e^x>0$, $\forall x≥0$. Then, since $e^{-x}=\frac 1{e^x}$ , this gives $e^x>0$, $\forall x \in\mathbb R$. Is this proof also circular?

Comment: That looks more like how I would have done it myself if it were known, but again it depends on what has or hasn't been introduced about the exponential function yet.  From what is listed here, it may as well have been asking about proving $\alpha^x>0$ where $\alpha$ is some as of yet unnamed unspecified constant who happens to satisfy the properties that $\alpha^0=1$ and $\alpha^x\alpha^y=\alpha^{x+y}$.  If these were the *only* properties we can know, not knowing anything more about exponentiation or logarithms then I'm more inclined to go with geetha's answer above.

Comment: To supplement JMoravitz's good points, the complex exponential satisfies the exponential law and $\exp(0) = 1$, but does not satisfy $\exp(z) > 0$ for all complex $z$. That means positivity cannot be established from the exponential law and value at $0$ alone, but instead relies on some property of the real numbers and continuous functions, such as the intermediate value theorem (and geetha290krm's comment). <> Is the intermediate value theorem available? If not, what is the workng definition of $e^{x}$ for real $x$?